# Selecting Razor markup elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to select elements from JavaScript when they are set with Razor markup?

For some reason, it is not working for me:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <input type="radio" name="site-btn" id="site-btn[@i]" autocomplete="off" />
}
```

The following JavaScript does not work to select the element:

```
$("#site-btn[0]")
```

But this one does:

```
$("input[name=site-btn]").first()
```

When I consult the page source while debugging, the ID is set correctly:

```
<input type="radio" name="site-btn" id="site-btn[0]" autocomplete="off" />
```

But attempting to select the element just returns a 0-length object as if it does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Escape square brackets with double back-slash.  ` $("#site-btn\\\[0\\\]") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape meta character i.e. `[]` with double `\\`

```
$("#site-btn\\[0\\]")
```

Comment: Right, thank you, that was a silly mistake. I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed.